# Does Blade Mail return Magical damage?

Tags: dota

In [playdota](http://www.playdota.com/items) about Blade Mail, blow sentence is writen:

> Returns any damage you take (after reductions) to the unit that dealt the damage (you still take the damage as well)

But physical or magical didn`t be mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes- all damage types, potentially even HP removal, are redirected to their source. This definitely includes both physical and magical damage.

Comment: HP removal isn't damage. Are you sure it works for HP removal?

Comment: @Pacerier No idea. As of the latest patch, HP removal isn't even a damage type anymore though.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm saying. HP removal isn't damage.